# what is the meaning of putting a return statement inside an angular.js controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an if statement inside my angular.js controller which if satisfied will change the $state of my app.

this is the line:

```
    if ($scope.cond1)
        $state.go(".main");
.. rest of controller code
```

If this if is satisfied i want the controller code to stop from continuing.
I achieved this with changing it to:

```
    if ($scope.cond1)
        return $state.go(".main");
.. rest of controller code
```

What i don't understand is why return works here. What does it actually do. I am writing in angular for along time and i never used 'return' in this way.

I am used to use it inside functions, how does it works here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing return in a function... return just stops the execution of that function, if the function that called your controller doesn't store the result in a variable, nobody cares about what you return.

Comment: I would add two things here 1. the return value of a controller is ignored by the caller. 2. A more elegant approach is `$state.go('.main'); return;`. There is no need to return a value. Just end the execution of the method by a return.

Answer (score 1):

> What i don't understand is why return works here.

Why does return work in any function?  Answer: Because that's the way the javascript language was programmed to work.  When a return statement is encountered in a function, no more statements in the function are executed.

> What does it actually do.

It returns the value that $state.go() returns.  All function calls in your code are replaced by the function's return value.  So in this line:

```
return $state.go(".main");
```

the fragment:

```
$state.go(".main")
```

is a function call. So $state.go() is replaced in your code by the return value of $state.go(), which produces this:

```
return $state.go(".main");
               |
               V
return <some value>;
```

Controllers look like this:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function() {

   //This is a callback function

})
```

A *callback function* is a function that YOU are not calling, so you have no way to access the return value.  If you define a function like this:

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

then you can write:

```
var result = add(3, 4);
```

add(3,4) is a function call, so it is replaced in your code by its return value, producing this:

```
var result = 7;
```

You could also call that function like this:

```
add(3,4);
```

and javascript will replace the function call by the function's return value, producing this:

```
7;
```

That is legal js, and because the value is not assigned to a variable it is discarded.

You never call your controller's callback function in your code.  Instead, you pass the callback function as an argument to angular's controller() function, which is presumably defined something like this:

```
function controller(name, callback) {
  ...
  ...
  if(attr.name === "ng-controller" && attr.value === name) {
    callback(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">... </div>` , what does `return $state.go(".main");` will  return here ?? This is the question

Comment: so why to return anything? no use huh!

Comment: The op could have just as easily have written:  `$state.go(".main"); return;`